# How to take out both html and css of the whole webpage using snappysnippet?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In snappysnippet we can only take out css and html of the selected element. But how to extract the whole webpage's css and html

Answer (score 0):

Click on sources option in snappysnippet, whole foulder structure will be displayed on leftpanel, right click on desired file and save as in your workspace.

For html code you can right click to the particular webpage and select View Source Code option.